# Testing Angular component, which changes based on observable service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I am trying to test the `login()` method of a component in Angular 4 which relies on an Observable `authService` that returns either a success or error:

Code under test:

```
login() {
    this.loginError = undefined;
    this.loadingService.present('Logging In...');

    this.authService
      .login(this.form.value)
      .subscribe(
        (currentUser: any) => {
          this.loadingService.dismiss();
          this.navCtrl
            .setRoot('TabsPage')
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this.loadingService.dismiss();
          this.loginError = error._body;
          console.error('LoginPage :: Login Error:', error);
        }
      );
}
```

I am aware that to successfully unit test this method, I need to isolate it. I have created a stub for the `authService`, and injected it into the `TestBed`:

Authentication Stub

```
export class AuthenticationServiceStub {

  login() {};

  getCurrentUserFromStorage() {};

  logout() {};

};
```

Testbed config:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ...components,
      ],
      providers: [
        NavController,
        LoadingService,
        FormBuilder,
        { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthenticationServiceStub }
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(LoginPage),
        PierDataServicesModule.forRoot(),
      ],
    });
```

It is my understanding, that to unit test `login()` I must test these 4 things:

1. `this.loginError` is set to undefined
2. `this.loadingService.present('Logging In...')` is called
3. `this.authService.login(this.form.value)` is called
4. If `this.authService.login(this.form.value)` returns success, that
       both methods in the success function block are called, and if an
       error, that the methods in the error block are called.

This is what my spec looks like, (I have managed to test 1, 2, 3):

Tests:

```
describe('Login()', () => {

  let fixture:      ComponentFixture<LoginPage>;
  let instance: any = null;
  let authService: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => TestUtils.beforeEachCompiler([LoginPage]).then(compiled => {

    fixture = compiled.fixture;
    instance = compiled.instance;

    spyOn(instance, 'login').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(instance.loadingService, 'present');
    spyOn(instance.authService, 'login').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });

    instance.login();

  })));

  it("should be callable", async(() => {
    expect(instance.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it("should call loadingService.present ", async(() => {
    expect(instance.loadingService.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it("should call authService.login", async() => {
    expect(instance.authService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


});
```

**I cannot figure out how to test number 4**. How can I replicate the Observable being called through with a success or an error, and check that the functions in those function bodies, run?

I could build out the mock `login()` method and duplicate the functionality from the code under test, but it seems really counterintuitive to test a mock method instead of the actual code.

Should I use the real `authService` method and build a mock a back end? is this something that works? if so, how?

Should I use Karma to `spyOn` the methods and modify them to do what I want? I imagined that I would be able to do something like this: `spyOn(instance.authService, 'login').and.callThrough().and.throwError()` but have had no success with that approach.

Comment: could you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real service shouldn't be involved in unit test because this will introduce additional moving parts.

A clean way to test promises and observables is to provide a real one, not an object that mimics them:

```
spyOn(instance.authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(null));
...
expect(instance.loadingService.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.navCtrl.setRoot).toHaveBeenCalledWith('TabsPage');
expect(instance.lognError).toBe(...);
...
const _body = {};
spyOn(instance.authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ _body }));
...
expect(instance.loadingService.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.navCtrl.setRoot).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.lognError).toBe(_body);
```